# How to build Redis 6 with TLS on Mac

Tags: macos, ssl, redis

I want to use TLS with Redis on Mac (macOS 10.15.4, kernel: Darwin 19.4.0). This is what I tried according to [Documentation](https://redis.io/topics/encryption):

```
export BUILD_TLS=yes
mkdir redis && cd redis
curl -O http://download.redis.io/redis-stable.tar.gz
tar xzvf redis-stable.tar.gz
cd redis-stable
make BUILD_TLS=yes
make test
sudo make install
```

All tests passed but when I run:

```
% redis-server --tls-cluster yes
```

I get error:

```
*** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR (Redis 6.0.4) *** Reading the configuration file, at line 2
>>> 'tls-cluster "yes"'
Bad directive or wrong number of arguments
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try to [`brew install redis`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/redis) (currently in version `6.0.5`) it includes already support for TLS, in any case, if you would like to compile it from the source you could check the brew formula: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/redis.rb#L18

```
def install
    system "make", "install", "PREFIX=#{prefix}", "CC=#{ENV.cc}", "BUILD_TLS=yes"

    %w[run db/redis log].each { |p| (var/p).mkpath }

    # Fix up default conf file to match our paths
    inreplace "redis.conf" do |s|
      s.gsub! "/var/run/redis.pid", var/"run/redis.pid"
      s.gsub! "dir ./", "dir #{var}/db/redis/"
      s.sub!  /^bind .*$/, "bind 127.0.0.1 ::1"
    end

    etc.install "redis.conf"
    etc.install "sentinel.conf" => "redis-sentinel.conf"
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

You did not specify the value for the `tls-cluster` configuration option. This works (on my MacBook Catelina 10.15.5):

```
% redis-server --tls-cluster yes
```

Comment: Still doesn't work, I get the same type of error. I now fixed my question and added missing "yes" that I lost when converting property file to command line flag. How did you install your redis-server? Did you use Homebrew?

Comment: No, I built it from the source.

Comment: I don't think this should work.

--tls-cluster yes (encrypts CLUSTER bus port 16379 not port 6379)

The below config may work.
port 0
tls-port 6379